# Automated Server Installs Config File- How to autoinstall config “fill disk”

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to create cloud config file “fill disk” (lvm)
Can someone can check and tell me what is the issue? ( getting error regarding root volume on ubuntu20.4 server foucs)

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
    disable_components: []
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches:
      - amd64
      - i386
      uri: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches:
      - default
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-test
    password: $6$XhlhJBcl/bxTQcSDA$BLAJBLAatDUh53b/BOEk1.c38CvU4XdlYjeltLav8EGcjpth/or5N33tLye6Og4TESYHFVr7MQaVGUn1tz2o67/Mm/
    realname: scadmin
    username: scadmin
  kernel:
    package: linux-generic
  keyboard:
    layout: us
    toggle: null
    variant: ''
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  network:
    ethernets:
      ens160:
        dhcp4: true
    version: 2
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  storage:
    config:
    - ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/sda
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: true
      type: disk
      id: disk-sda
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1048576
      flag: bios_grub
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: -1
      wipe: superblock
      flag: ''
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-1
    - name: vg0
      devices:
      - partition-1
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - name: lv-root
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: -1
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-0
    - name: lv-swap
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 4290772992B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-1
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-2
    - path: /
      device: format-2
      type: mount
      id: mount-2
    - fstype: swap
      volume: lvm_partition-1
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-3
    - path: ''
      device: format-3
      type: mount
      id: mount-3
    swap:
      swap: 0
  updates: security
  version: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your swap logical volume first by rearranging the storage config entries.

You create a root logical volume that will use all the space.

```
    - name: lv-root
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: -1
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-0
```

*Then* you create the swap logical volume.

```
    - name: lv-swap
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 4290772992B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-1
```

The installer does not like this.  I got this error log (using the 22.04 installer).

```
LVM_LogicalVolume(name='lv-root', volgroup=lvm_volgroup-0, size=-1, wipe='superblock', type='lvm_partition', id='lvm_partition-0') has negative size but is not final partition of LVM_VolGroup(name='vg0', devices=[partition-1], type='lvm_volgroup', id='lvm_volgroup-0')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 preserve: false
  grub_device: false
  type: partition
  id: partition-3
- fstype: ext4
  volume: partition-3
  preserve: false
  type: format
  id: format-0
- name: lv-swap
  volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
  size: 4294967296B
  wipe: superblock
  preserve: false
  type: lvm_partition
  id: lvm_partition-0
- name: lv-root
  volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
  size: 25765609472B
  wipe: superblock
  preserve: false
  type: lvm_partition
  id: lvm_partition-1
- fstype: ext4
  volume: lvm_partition-1
  preserve: false
  type: format
  id: format-3
- path: /
  device: format-3
  type: mount
  id: mount-3
- fstype: swap
  volume: lvm_partition-0
  preserve: false
  type: format
  id: format-4
- path: ''
  device: format-4
  type: mount
  id: mount-4
- path: /boot
  device: format-0
  type: mount
  id: mount-0
```